# Web Site Hi Jacked

Tags: safari, ipad

Parallels has taken over a web site on Safari on my Ipad so that whenever I type in the address Parallels opens. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify, just a specific web site or all of web sites. If it is specific, please show the web site address here (copy paste)

Comment: The web address would help as it may be a website that links to the app.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing here due to incomplete information.

Check your Safari Preference settings. Make sure it is what you want.
Check the Search Engine, Home page, new widow settings.

Find the website in question in your history and delete it than type it new in the Safari browser window. I assume you have no odd Safari plug ins installed?